# Postgres query returning books with only one author

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make a query returning the book title, the book summary and the author name from the books with only one author ordered by the book id. A book can have many authors and an author can write many books, so it's a many to many relationship, but I'm making something wrong or forgetting something.

My tables are:

```
book_tb(id, title, summary);
author_tb(id, name);
book_author_tb(id, book_id, author_id);
```

And I have tried:

```
SELECT b.title, b.summary, a.name 
FROM book_tb b
INNER JOIN book_author_tb ba ON b.id = ba.book_id
INNER JOIN author_tb a ON ba.author_id = a.id
GROUP BY b.title, b.summary, a.name, b.id
HAVING count(ba.author_id) = 1
ORDER BY b.id;
```

Comment: Could you please post data sample and how the output should look like?

Comment: Yes, having `a.name` in the `GROUP BY` list you get one group for each author, where `HAVING count(ba.author_id) = 1` is always true.

Comment: What do you mean by one author? Is it a book that has only one author or you want to select all books and if a book has more than one author then a random one should be selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing this is:

```
SELECT b.title, b.summary, a.name 
FROM book_author_tb ba 
INNER JOIN book_tb b ON b.id = ba.book_id
INNER JOIN author_tb a ON a.id = ba.author_id
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM book_author_tb
  WHERE book_id = b.id
) = 1
ORDER BY b.id
```

This:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM book_author_tb WHERE book_id = b.id
```

makes sure that the books returned have only 1 author.
Another way (maybe more efficient):

```
SELECT b.title, b.summary, a.name 
FROM (
  SELECT book_id, MAX(author_id) author_id 
  FROM book_author_tb
  GROUP BY book_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) ba 
INNER JOIN book_tb b ON b.id = ba.book_id
INNER JOIN author_tb a ON a.id = ba.author_id
ORDER BY b.id
```

Comment: Verified with a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9c11fc30a96ad78d706c8accb91a1402) (SQL Server), it is working.

Comment: In the second case you can avoid one join by adding to subselect `max(author_id) as author_id`

Comment: Which join would I avoid? I still need to join to author_tb to get the author's name.

Comment: I mean first `book_author_tb ba`

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with just aggregation:

```sql
  SELECT b.title
        ,b.summary
        ,MAX(a.name) AS name
    FROM book_author_tb AS ba
      INNER JOIN book_tb AS b 
        ON b.id = ba.book_id
      INNER JOIN author_tb AS a 
        ON a.id = ba.author_id
    GROUP BY b.title
            ,b.summary
    HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

This version is counting the number of authors on each book (assuming no duplicates, which is reasonable).

Your version is also aggregating by the author.  The `count()` is only going to be "1" in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate count of authors the filter you want in a different subselect. So you can use it in you WHERE statement from now on.

```
     SELECT b.title, b.summary, a.name FROM book_tb b
     JOIN book_author_tb ba ON b.id = ba.book_id
     JOIN author_tb a ON ba.author_id = a.author_id
     GROUP BY b.title, b.summary, a.name, b.id
     WHERE (SELECT count(ba.author_id) 
                FROM book_author_tb
                WHERE book_id = b.id) = 1
     ORDER BY b.id;
```